# Bundle .net exe, dlls, .net environment and Native dll in single exe

Tags: c#, windows, gcc

I am trying to bundle my C# application(.exe) with its dependent dlls, a Native dll and required .net assemblies to single exe using mkbundle.

So, first of all is it possible to do so using mono mkbundle?

If yes, when I try to do it using command

```
C:\MyProjDir>mkbundle -o BundleName --deps OriginalAppName.exe
```

When compiling

```
as -o temp.o temp.s
```

I get error:

> 'as' is not recognized as an internal
>   or external command, operable program or batch file. [Fail]

I found somewhere that I need to install gcc, gcc-mingw and as packages. (sic). I did install gcc, gcc-mingw but I don't know where to find as packages which is the error.
Please suggest if there is any other way of doing it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx)

For the Native DLL you can embed the DLL as an application resource, and extract the resource to disk at the time of execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that directly from your application,

- as Michael G suggested, put the native DLL as a resource and load it accordingly
- the use https://www.nuget.org/packages/Costura.Fody/1.3.2 package, it will embed all .NET assemblies your project references, thus creating a stand-alone executable